Frobenius Endomorphism does not preserve injectivity
Frobenius Endomorphism
Let $R$ be a ring of prime characteristic $p>0$. The Frobenius endomorphism is the map $F: R\to R$ defined by $r\mapsto r^p$ for any $r\in R$. For any $R$-module $M$, we can derive an $R$-module structure from the Frobenius endomorphism on the set $M$ by $r\cdot m:=r^{p}m$ for any $r\in R$ and $m\in M$. We denote this $R$-module by ${}^1\!M$.
Change of base functor
Let $f: R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. There is a base change functor $S\otimes_R -$ that sends $R$-modules $M$ to $S$-modules $S\otimes_R M$ and $R$-linear maps $h: M\to N$ to $S$-linear maps $1_S\otimes_R h: S\otimes_R M\to S\otimes_R N$.
Define $\mathcal F_R$ to be the Frobenius change of base functor, where we simply set $S=R$ and $f=F$, the Frobenius endomorphism.
My question
Let $M\subseteq N$ be $R$-modules. Let $\iota: M\to N$ be the inclusion map. Then, apparently, $\mathcal F_R(\iota): \mathcal F_R(M)\to \mathcal F_R(N)$ may not be injective.
I cannot see this. We have $\mathcal F_R(\iota): R\otimes_R M\to R\otimes_R N$, which is defined by $s\otimes m\mapsto s\otimes \iota(m)$ for every $s\in R$ and $m\in M$. But $\iota(m)=m$, so how is this not simply another inclusion map, and therefore, injective?

For extra context, I am working from this paper https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/711F07/L09.12.pdf

Be careful with tensor products; if $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules with $M \subset N$, it is possible for to have an $m\in M$ such that $1 \otimes m = 0$ in $R\otimes_R N$ but $1 \otimes m \neq 0$ in $R\otimes_R M$. For example, $1 \otimes 2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}$, but $1 \otimes 2\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} 2\mathbb{Z}$.

If $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ of characteristic $p > 0$ and $\iota : I \to R$ is the inclusion, then $\mathcal{F}_R(\iota) : \mathcal{F}_R(I) \to \mathcal{F}_R(R)$ is identified with $F : I \to R$, $u\mapsto u^p$.

This question is essentially asking whether $^1{R}$ (with the module structure induced by $F$) is a flat $R$-module (i.e., whether $F$ is a flat ring homomorphism).

It's tricky to see what's going on here because the notation kind of makes it look like Frobenius change of base isn't doing anything at all to morphisms. So let's look more carefully at that definition
$$1_S \otimes_R h : S \otimes_R M \to S \otimes_R N.$$
This tensor product is $R$-bilinear, and that means something funny when we take $F : R \to R$ to be the Frobenius: it means that if $r \in R, m \in M$ then
$$1 \otimes rm = r^p \otimes m \in R \otimes_R M$$
and similarly $1 \otimes rh = r^p \otimes h$. This means that it's possible that we could have $rm \neq 0 \in M$ but $1 \otimes rm = r^p \otimes m = 0 \in R \otimes_R M$, if for example $r \neq 0$ but $r^p = 0$.
So let's try to make this happen. We can just take $R = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p)$, and consider the inclusion $i : I \hookrightarrow R$ of the ideal $I = (x)$ into $R$. Then $x \in I$ is nonzero, and so is $i(x) \in R$, but
$$F(i(x)) = 1 \otimes i(x) = x^p \otimes 1 = 0 \in R$$
so $F(i) : F(I) \to F(R)$ is not injective.

 Abstractly, as Geoffrey says in the comments, the desired property (that $F$ preserves injections) is equivalent to $F$ being exact, or to $R$ being flat as a module over itself with respect to Frobenius. The above construction shows that a necessary condition for this to be true is that the Frobenius is injective; equivalently, that $R$ has to be reduced.

